# Requesting int input, how to guard against char?

Tags: c, input, char, int, scanf

I'm asking for int input, and then checking whether it is equal to the correct answer, but how  do I guard against users inputting chars?

```
    int main()
    {
       int response;
       int answer;

       scanf("%f", &response);
       if(response == answer)
       {
         //Correct! 
       }
       else
       {
         //Incorrect!
       }
    }
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings, e.g. with `gcc -Wall`

Answer (score 3):

[scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) gives a result (the count of successfully read items), that you should use. And your `%f` is incorrect, so you should code

```
if (scanf(" %d", &response)==1) { 
  /// did got some response
}
```

<sup>I took into account the good [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19748706/296974#comment29346328_19748781) of [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in the [answer of Soumya Koumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) ...</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use `%d` for scanning an *int* from input.

According to [`scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) definition it returns the number of items scanned if successful or 0 in case there is a matching failure. So if you enter a *char* instead of an *integer* in the standard input it will return 0 as the return value.

You can do something like:

```
if (scanf(....) == 0) { 
    /* error */ 
} else {
    /* do my work */
}
```

Comment: It is better to test for the exact number of items you expect (`if (scanf(...) != 1) { report error; } else { do real work; }` because `scanf()` can return -1 on EOF as well as 0 (and it might report 3 if there were 17 conversion specifications in the format string, meaning it got stuck after 3 successful conversions, leaving 1 attempted but failed conversion, and 13 unattempted conversions).